# Connect to mysql using Zaphir

Tags: php, mysql, zephir

How can I connect to my sql using **Zephir**, also I'm using php, I tried the [link](http://zephir-lang.com/oop.html) but failed.

this is how I use the code.

```
public function setConnection(connection) -> void
{
    let this->_connection = connection;
}

let myDb = db->setConnection(connection);
myDb->execute("SELECT * FROM robots");
```

it gives only a vauge idea and throws exception

thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2):

You assign the return value of `setConnection`
to myDb. 
(which gets set to null, since setConnection does not return anything)
Then you call `myDb->execute` which is `NULL->execute()`.

So you call a function of null, insteadof on an object.

Comment: Your code just doesn't make sense. Where is this execute method defined? Do you want to call it on your class or on connection or do you want something completly different?

Comment: what i am trying is to make a connection with database using Zephyr. any method will do

Comment: It's just as in PHP. Declare a class, which you feed the connection credentials to (constructor). Create a connection instance (via PDO, also constructor) and save it to a property. (also constructor + error handling code). Then declare a function exec, which you can call with a query. I would also recommend supporting prepared statements. If you are not experienced enough to do it in PHP, you can't do it in Zephir.